# Can't read and write from adb shell

Tags: android, python, shell, unix, subprocess

I'm trying to control a terminal with Python. According to documentation I've found, I should be able to use Popen to run terminal commands, with stdin and stdout output. Unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
import subprocess
o = subprocess.Popen("adb shell",stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
#for line in o:
#print "I got",line
print o.communicate("ls /")
o.stdin.write("ls /")
o.stdin.flush()
print o.stdout.read()
print o.readline();
print o.communicate()
```

EDIT - I tried monkeyrunner instead, it seems to be made for this task, but unfortunately it fails with an error:

```
>>> device.shell('su')
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] Error executing command: su
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice]com.android.ddmlib.ShellCommandUnresponsiveException
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.executeRemoteCommand(AdbHelper.java:408)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.ddmlib.Device.executeShellCommand(Device.java:388)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice.shell(AdbChimpDevice.java:269)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyDevice.shell(MonkeyDevice.java:217)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(PyReflectedFunction.java:175)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:355)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:215)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyMethod.instancemethod___call__(PyMethod.java:221)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyMethod.__call__(PyMethod.java:206)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:397)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(PyObject.java:401)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.pycode._pyx19.f$0(<stdin>:1)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.pycode._pyx19.call_function(<stdin>)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:165)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1197)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.core.Py.exec(Py.java:1241)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.exec(PythonInterpreter.java:147)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runcode(InteractiveInterpreter.java:89)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(InteractiveInterpreter.java:70)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter.runsource(InteractiveInterpreter.java:46)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.push(InteractiveConsole.java:110)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.interact(InteractiveConsole.java:90)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at org.python.util.InteractiveConsole.interact(InteractiveConsole.java:60)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.ScriptRunner.console(ScriptRunner.java:193)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.run(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:73)
120706 08:29:28.433:S [main] [com.android.chimpchat.adb.AdbChimpDevice] at com.android.monkeyrunner.MonkeyRunnerStarter.main(MonkeyRunnerStarter.java:189)
```

Comment: try `shell=True`, but that may not be safe and probably the "acquiring root privileges" you're doing is wrong...

Comment: You're right, that was dumb example. See updated script, it at least started with shell=True, but still doesn't work.

Comment: What doesn't work? have you tried using `.communicate`?

Comment: It only shows an empty screen. Yes, I've tried communicate.

Comment: You know Popen will wait to the process to end? Are you sure the `adb shell` thing is over?

Comment: I want to enter, and receive result from the shell, it should only exit when I send the command.

Comment: You probably want [pexpect](http://www.noah.org/python/pexpect/)

Comment: Since you are trying to run adb, you might actually want a python adb client instead. http://code.google.com/p/powerdroid/source/browse/trunk/src/droid/adb.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well. `monkeyrunner` can do what you showed as an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env monkeyrunner

from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner

cmd = 'ls /'
print cmd+':', MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection().shell(cmd)
```

Comment: Where do I get this package? I have Android SDK but I can't import that.

Comment: You should use monkeyrunner as the interpreter

Comment: Nice find. It works well for some commands, but I can't run 'su', even though superuser says it was allowed.

Comment: Although su doesn't work, shell("su -c 'ls /data/'") does. I guess MonkeyRunner fails when it waits for input?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
o = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

the command has to be a list i believe.  Make sure `adb` is in the path of the python process.

Comment: But only if `shell=False` (the default). A shell expects a command line.

Answer (score 0):

you can try out :

```
import os
ls=os.popen('ls').read()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import subprocess
o = subprocess.Popen(["adb", "shell"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
o.stdin.write("ls /")
o.stdin.write("\n")
o.stdin.flush()
o.stdout.readline()
```